# Colouring a particular cell of fishnet grid in ArcMap 10.8

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, layers, symbology, vector-grid

I am using ArcMap10.8 on a Windows laptop. How do I select a specific cell of a fishnet grid and fill it with a colour of my choice? Each cell is labelled with a number. The fishnet grid is overlayed on a shapefile and the ArcMap file has LULC and urbanization density index features shown as well.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Selecting a specific cell can be accomplished in a number of ways, as can rendering it in a specific color. What have tried, and where are you stuck?